# remove from select laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm creating a system where a club has multiple teams, and in every team can be users (users can be in multiple teams)

Now all the eloquent things work for selecting all the things :)

but now I want to generate a list of all users from the a club that are NOT in the team already

now I just normal select the users by doing the following:

`$team->club->users()->lists('name','id')`

This is on the team page, so first I get the club the team is from and then I get all the users, and only select the name and Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Laravel pretty extensively over the last six months and I think what you're looking for is the "whereNotIn" functionality of Eloquent.

Here's an example, based on my application:

```
$user = User::whereNotIn('id', function($query) {
    $query->select('id')
          ->from('hospital_user')
          ->where('hospital_user.hospital_id', '=', 54);
})->lists('email', 'id');
```

This could be simplified like:

```
$hospital = Hospital::findOrFail(54);
$users = User::whereNotIn('id', $hospital->users()->lists('user_id'))
             ->lists('email', 'id');
```

I hope my example helps. What I've done here is selected all of my users which are not in the hospital_user pivot table for the specific hospital.

Comment: Yea I've tried doing that with the following: `$team->club->users()->whereNotIn('id', $team->users()->lists('id'))->lists('name','id')` but then I get ` Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: Okay, here's the solution: `$team->club->users()->whereNotIn('id', $team->users()->lists('user_id'))->lists('name','id')`

Comment: One small thing (still debugging, so not sure) what if the $team->users() is empty, then the whereNotIn is trying to "filter" but the array is empty. isn't this going to be a problem?

Comment: nvm, fixed that doing it this way `                @if (($users = $team->club->users()->whereNotIn('id', (($teamUsers = $team->users()->lists('user_id')) != null) ? $teamUsers : [0] )->lists('name','id')) != null)` that's my full if function for also checking if it is still possible to add users, the $users get's passed on in the select

Comment: You wouldn't have a problem if it's empty. It would return all users.

Comment: IT gave an error, that's why I needed the workaround